# Javascript counter++ skips counting

Tags: javascript, counter

I am building a simple JS game but ++ keeps on adding up for no reason.
Here is the code:

```
var cities = ["Atlanta","Chicago","Honolulu","Houston","Nashville","Orlando","Philadelphia","Phoenix","Portland","Seattle"],
    c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)),
    city = cities[c].toUpperCase(),
    cityArr = city.split(""),
    length = city.length,
    guess = 0,
    $prompt = $('#prompt'),
    x, //letter guess
    i;

function randomCity() {
    var $showCity = document.getElementById("showCity"), //ul
        newLi,
        letter;//each letter of city

    for(i=0; i<cityArr.length; i++){
        newLi = document.createElement("li");
        $showCity.appendChild(newLi);
        letter = document.createTextNode(cityArr[i]);
        newLi.appendChild(letter);
    }
    $("#showCity li").css("color", "#fff");
}//end randomCity()

function play() {
    if(guess == 6){
        $("#alphabet").css("visibility", "hidden");
        ending();
    } else {
        $prompt.fadeIn("slow").text("Guess a letter: ");
        guessLetter();
    }
} // end play function

function guessLetter() {
    var showLetter;
    guess++
    console.log(guess); //SHOWS THE COUNTER ADDING UP CONTINUOUSLY AFTER 2

    $("#alphabet li").on('click', function () {
        $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        x = this.id;

        if (city.indexOf(x) == -1) {
            $prompt.fadeIn("slow").text("No letter " + x);
            setTimeout(play, 1500);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (city[i] == x) {
                    $prompt.fadeIn("slow").text("There is letter " + x + "!");
                    showLetter = "#showCity li:nth-child("+(i+1)+")";
                    $(showLetter).css("color", "#0F9ED8");
                }
            } //for loop
            setTimeout(play, 1500);
        } //else
    });
}

function ending(){ //STILL IN PROGRESS
    var guessWord,
        finalOutput;

    $prompt.fadeIn("slow").text("What is the word? ");
    //guessWord = word from input
    finalOutput = (guessWord == city) ? "That is correct!" : "Sorry, that is wrong.";
    $prompt.fadeIn("slow").text(finalOutput);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").on('click', function() {
        $(this).hide();
        randomCity();
        console.log(city);
        $("#alphabet").css("visibility", "visible");
        play();
    });
}); // end ready
```

variable guess (the counter) has value of 4 after clicking the 2nd element, and has a value of 6 after clicking the 3rd element. I moved the var guess in different parts of my code but it is still doing that. This is very weird!

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
$("#alphabet li").on('click', function () { /* ... */}`
```

you're binding a new click handler every time the `guessLetter()` function gets executed. Multiple click handlers will call the `play()` function which in turn calls the `guessLetter()` function again, resulting in `guess` being incremented multiple times.

Bind the click handler only once.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer: bind it only once, e.g. in your `document.ready()` handler.

Comment: I moved the onclick event to document.ready(), and now the guess counter is counting by itself without being clicked

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching a new click handler to your list items every time the `guessLetter` function is called.

To fix it, you could move everything in `guessLetter` which occurs after your console.log call into the `$(document).ready` callback function.

Comment: What is the solution for this?